# Indoor tabletop security camera that does not require outside cloud storage and easiest to setup

Tags: video-camera, home-security

This may or may not be a duplicate question, but please read on before deciding.

So I have tried the foscam brand, but found that they have the you figure it out approach to setup. I have never set up a tabletop indoor security camera before and found foscam to be a pain. There was something about using some IP, but was never sure if it was the IP of my router. If it was the IP of the camera, then tough because I had no clue what it was or where it was.

So basically, I am looking for an indoor tabletop camera that I can control from my iPhone, even if I am 3 to 10 hours away from my home.

I found that foscam worked great if I was home, once I left home, I could not connect to the camera via the foscam app.

So I am looking for something with excellent documentation on how to setup, preferably does not require me to use third-party cloud storage and preferably does not require me to go to NO IP or some other website to complete setup.

Something that is as easy as 1, 2, 3 and now I am off to Paris and can still open an app on my iPhone and view what my camera sees. Or something close to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wyze Cams are simple to setup and simple to use. While they have cloud storage capabilities, they do not have to be used. You can put in a high capacity microSD and record right to the card. The live cameras can be accessed remotely, as well as the footage. They have fixed cameras and cameras that pan. Did I mention that they're inexpensive as well? You can purchase them directly from Wyze, Amazon, Micro Center, or Home Depot.

Check them out: https://wyze.com/